# Is Wear OS the way to go for a programmable watch?

Tags: android-wear

I had a hard time finding the right Stack Exchange site to post this on but here it is.

I have a Polar watch, the problem is its lack of customizability. I am therefore looking for a programmable watch that has GPS capabilities. This would let me take control of the watch's interface.

I have looked into Wear OS and it looks promising. I not sure however which watch is compatible with this OS...

I have found this watch [Zeblaze THOR PRO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07F8L1SG3). If I come to buy this watch, will I be able to program my own app and implement it on this watch?

Comment: All I can find about the device is that it is running Android 5.1 not Android Wear OS or Samsung Tizen. While you could program Android on that watch it would probably only have phone APIs. You may have better luck asking in one of the resources listed in [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/3573)